# any package that prints the dual matrix?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I tried asking this problem over stackoverflow but thought this would be more appropriate place to ask.

I am having a Primal problem, say

```
min x1 + 2x2
st 2x1 + 3x2 >= 6
   5x1 - 7x2 >= 8
    x1,x2 >= 0
```

and the dual is

```
max 6y1 + 8y2
    2y1+5y2 <= 1
    3y1-7y2 <= 2
      y1,y2>=0
```

Is there a software, say Lp_solve or glpk or Gurobi which can print the dual problem(like the coefficient matrix and objective coefficients of dual) when primal is given?

Comment: Do you mean transpose?

Comment: yes. But say if there are 20 variables, then having a software if nice.

Comment: Most software package have a built in transpose function. In matlab for example `A.'`.

Comment: @Morpheus The dual problem is not just the transposed problem of the primal problem. Why do you Need a Software for the Transformation of a primal problem (et vis versa) ?

Comment: @user251257 The dual problem is not just the transposed problem of the primal problem.

Comment: @calculus the comment was only about the coefficient matrix. in general not, but in his standard form yes.

Comment: @user251257 The difficulties are the (in-)equality signs of the constraints and the signs of the variables. Transposing a matrix is not really a challenge.

Comment: @calculus I know. But op did not ask the dual problem, but only for the coefficient matrix and the objective vector. Again in his standard form it is not a great challenge.

Comment: @user251257 Maybe you are right, that the OP needs only the transposed matrix. If not the OP can/will leave a comment.

Comment: I found my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a web app called Simplex online calculator at [mathtools.com](http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/simplex_online_calculator#.VgQEY5cpxSA)

Thanks for the help